# What is the use of comma in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to elixir and was going through sample chat application written in it using phoenix framework.
I am not able to understand meaning of this line

```
channel "rooms:*", Chat.RoomChannel
```

I searched online for this type of syntax but could not got the answer I was looking for. I know that `Chat.RoomChannel` is a module and `channel` follows a string which identifies type of room under consideration

I want to know how that syntax works

Comment: This is equivalent to `channel("rooms:*", Chat.RoomChannel)` which may look more familiar to you. The parens are optional.

Comment: Got it! thnx @ChrisMartin :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma seperates the argument list.

I guess you are getting confused that this is a function call.
In elixir when calling a function its optional to give paranthesis. So

```
channel "rooms:*", Chat.RoomChannel
```

Is equivalent to

```
channel("rooms:*", Chat.RoomChannel)
```